# Console log in a single line

Tags: javascript

I want to Write a program that prints numbers from 1 to 1000 Using For Loop. All numbers should be printed in the same line separated by comma and space (like this: 1, 2, 3).but i cant figure it out how to do it in for loop I am a beginner 
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create the array and then use keys to join with [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
console.log([...Array(1000).keys()].join(', '));
```

**OR:** You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method which creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object:

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(1000).keys()).join(', '));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and not the one linked as duplicate